# How does spanning a vector space working here?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I was watching "MIT OCW Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang" and in the lecture 9(Independence, Basis & Dimension), while explaining basis he said-

Vectors (1,1,2) & (2,2,5) doesn't span the space R^3. But Vectors (1,1,2), (2,2,5) & (3,3,8) does span the space R^3.

I don't understand how those 3 vectors span the entire vector space R^3 and then why those 2 alone can't do it?

Comment: Imagine all linear combinations of two vectors. The biggest span they could possibly have is a plane, $\mathbb R^2$; there is no way for them to "enter" the third dimension. Adding a third vector that can "sweep" this plane up and down in the third dimension increases the span to $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector spanned by two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ is any vector that can expressed a linear combination of these two vectors, i.e., $u$ is in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ if there exists scalars $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that

$ u = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 $

Now from your knowledge about the three dimensional space you know that such a linear combination of two vectors can at most cover a (two-dimensional) plane.

To cover all of the three dimensional space, we need three (linearly-independent)
vectors $v_1$ , $v_2$, $v_3$.  By linearly independent I mean that none of the three vectors can be expressed as linear combination of the other two.

Thus given any 3D vector $u$, you want to find scalars $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that

$ u = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 $

This can be written in matrix-vector form as:

$ u = A c $

where $A = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 && v_2 && v_3 \end{bmatrix} $

and $c = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\c_2\\c_3\end{bmatrix} $

As it turns out, $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent if and only if matrix $A$ is invertible, and if this the case then,

$c = A^{-1} u $

for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^3 $, i.e. any $u$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3$, and hence the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the fundamental results in linear algebra. Namely, suppose $S = \{v_1, \dots, v_m\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $S$ is linearly independent, then $m \leq n$. If $S$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $m \geq n$.

Both of these results follow easily from the theorem that any set of $n + 1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly dependent. Proofs of this theorem can be found in most linear algebra books, e.g. here on page 18:
https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/linear-algebra-notes/